Are positively charged particles defined to have an electric field pointing radially outward or is it just a convention?
Are positively charged particles defined to have an electric field pointing radially outward or are particles with field pointing outward defined as positive? Even if we swap the idea with negative particles everything would everything work? So is it just a convention we decided to use? I mean even if we take positive particles to have a field pointing radially inward, we could take a positive charge to always experience a force in the opposite direction of the field.

Are positively charged particles defined to have an electric field pointing radially outward or is it just a convention? Is there a relevant difference between a definition and a convention? In both cases you could do it the opposite way.

By convention I mean to ask if it is something is just a common practice and if it could work both ways. In this case if there is no definite direction of the field for any particle, you could take any direction for any particle just keeping in mind that two different types (positive or negative) would attract. But if certain particles do have a field pointing outward (considering it as a property of them), then they could be called as positive (that is a definition to my understanding). Does this show a difference?

Yes, it is a convention that the electric field is proportional to the force a positive test charge would experience. Because a positive test charge is repelled from a positive charge this means the electric field points radially outwards from positive charges. We could still do physics with this convention reversed.
